# Caching on the Web. How are address initial visits treated in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

When a visitor visits http://www.yourwebpage.com/

Is there a way to have the browser use the **previously cached response**? Or will it always make a request to the server?

I am guessing a request to the server will occur, but is then possible to respond with an empty string, and let the browser automatically use **the cached response** for index.html? Or do you always have to **supply the entire answer**?

The question is related to how much the initial index.html response for a JS based application should contain or if the index.html response should make a second request for html pieces and such.

```
// Example: Pseudo code
<html> ... 
    <script> 
          if ( !localStorage.index ) { 
               localStorage.index = loadFromServer( 'head.html' ) 
          }
          document.head.append(localStorage.index); 
    </script>
...</html>
```

The question boils down to, if i have ten templates.html files, which I would like to serve once, should they be included in the index.html response or should another request be made to fetch these as one bundle.

Obviously, if I make a second request, the browser will cache that response if proper headers are set, but that would cost another request, at least the first time.

**If I include them in the index.html** then the initial response will be bigger, but less than the two requests otherwise necessary, but how will subsequent requests to fetch the index.html be treated?

I have never visited a page who do not load something, although teoretically if the proper cached-headers from previous request has been set properly, it should be possible to treat it as an offline application, or is cache now applicable for initial requests? Only for requests made for instance by ajax or

**Is the last statement true?**

Basically, could you execute JavaScript by visiting a webpage using only cached data, that is without actually needing to make any request, or at least wait for an answer.

Is this possible? Perhaps storing the entire index.html in the localStorage is one way and have the index.html response the second time respond with only a script tag saying load from localStorage.

**EDIT 1**

I have come to understand that there is something called a Manifest for at least Firefox which can allow for the treatment as such as an application install the first time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your web server (and/or web app framework) should use cache headers to give this sort of instruction to the browser.  Cache headers include etags and cache-control.  A full example and explanation is here:  https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL

But basically, those tell the browser when to consider the fetched content stale, when to actually make a request.  Further, if the server knows the information hasn't been changed, it will respond with a HTTP 304 response, which will result in the client using the cached copy instead as well.

You really don't need to use the localstorage option unless you want your JS to definitely never ask the server for something unless it's not in localstorage.  The problem with that is that you then have to manage your own cache invalidation, etc.